# Exifs image, convert ExposureProgram number

Tags: php, exif

I need to upload images and get Exif to display.

I'm using `exif_read_data` to get exifs data.

```php
$data = exif_read_data($imageFile, 'EXIF', true);
```

Everything is fine, but :

```
$data['EXIF']['ExposureProgram'] = 3
```

I know Exposure Programm could be :

- aperture priority
- shutter priority
- auto
- manuel

I don't find any information about this number and what is its meaning.

Maybe someone can help me here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not checking [Exif's Standard 2.32](https://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-X008-Translation-2019-E.pdf) itself? Page 50:

> 0 = Not defined
> 1 = Manual
> 2 = Normal program
> 3 = Aperture priority
> 4 = Shutter priority
> 5 = Creative program (biased toward depth of field)
> 6 = Action program (biased toward fast shutter speed)
> 7 = Portrait mode (for closeup photos with the background out of focus)
> 8 = Landscape mode (for landscape photos with the background in focus)
> Other = reserved

[Phil Harvey's ExifTool reference](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html) is also worth to check for additional improper values from vendors violating the standard(s):

> (the value of 9 is not standard EXIF, but is used by the Canon EOS 7D)
>
> 9 = Bulb

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer !
I didn't know Exif's standard was existing, I find nothing like this in my searches.
I gonna check it when I can ;)

Comment: In doubt always read at least [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif#External_links) to a given topic, as it always links to official websites and standards.